# How to convert contours found by OpenCV into smooth splines or Bezier-like curves

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm vectorizing a color bitmap: shortly, I find the number of colors, extract each color as b/w mask, and detect contours, then dump everything into the file as SVG. But the result is poor due to very crispy and rough contours for the color edges. Also, I get a lot of noise ("salt and pepper") which adds too many small contours to the output.

[image: Issues]

In order to eliminate "salt and pepper" I've tried to apply different blur effects (median blur, gaussian) prior to contour detection as well as morphological operators (erode/dilate/open/close), they all are not suitable for my case, because they blur or even remove tiny objects/contours that must stay sharp.

Finally, I ended up with an idea to convert a set of points from detected contours into a spline or Bezier curve, but haven't found a way to do that with the arrays returned by cv2.findContour(...).

As an experiment, I tried to apply `c = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, simplification_param, False)` to the contours but they become more angular and broken, rather than smooth and continuous.

Is there a way to convert the result of cv2.approxPolyDP(...) into splines or use some other library to get the same results like approxPolyDP but with Bezier curves?

These are the examples of b/w masks that I use to determine contours via cv2.findContours(...). Ultimately, they should be converted into smooth continuous curves (not necessarily connected or closed contours).

[image: Mask]

[image: Mask]

Thanks!

Comment: `approxPolyDP` will distort the curves more than should be acceptable for "vectorizing" images. this can be demonstrated with a square with rounded corners. nor will it be giving you splines. OpenCV, to my knowledge, has no splines or anything that uses splines. you will need to write your own code or use a library for your purpose. you aren't doing Computer Vision. OpenCV is the wrong tool for the job.